# Centos 6 to Centos 7 cgroups

Tags: centos, cgroups

I'm trying to set up resource limits per user in Centos 7, but I can't find the right commands for the new implementation of cgroups (I did read [the documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html) but it talks about restricting services not users).

This are the steps in Centos 6

1. Add to `/etc/cgconfig.conf`

   `group mygroup{
       cpu {
               cpu.shares = 200;
       }
       memory {
               memory.limit_in_bytes = 128m;
       }
   }`
2. Restart `service cgconfig restart`
3. Start in system boot: `chkconfig cgconfig on`
4. Verify groups added correctly: `lscgroup`
5. Add the processes for which we wish to limit resources to the cgroups we created: add to `/etc/cgrules.conf`

   `myuser       cpu,memory      mygroup/`
6. start the cgred service for the cgrules configuration changes to take effect: `service cgred start`
7. make sure the cgred service is enabled to start on system boot so that our rules persist across reboots: `chkconfig cgred on`

What is the **equivalent in Centos 7?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a [solution in ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/742752/centos-6-to-centos-7-cgroups)

```
systemctl set-property user-1000.slice CPUShares=100
```